# How to process data at less than camera's frame per second ability?

Tags: c++, frame-rate

i am not sure of how to put my question properly so here it goes.

I am running an object detection algorithm which runs at 40 frame per seconds (fps) and fitted on a camera which acts as an 'eye' on a robot. Then, I process the information which is received from the algorithm and pass the actions to my robot.

The issue is each time, the algorithm runs, it gives me slightly new reading. I guess its because as it processes data every 40 times per second, it will give new information. But I don't need new information if my robot doesn't move as most of the objects are at the same position at the previous frame.

My question, how can i only enhance my algorithm to only give me information each time if there is a change in object positions? by comparing last frame reading with current frame reading for example

Comment: How will you know that the new frame has no change in object positions without processing it? Perhaps you can implement a quick algorithm that determines if the new image is "interesting", and only have your main algorithm run on the image if it is.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to find the motion estimation of the image ,I think MPG-4 video is using an algorithm like that.

http://www.img.lx.it.pt/~fp/cav/Additional_material/MPEG4_video.pdf

But if you don't want something so sophisticated and you just want to be see if the second image is the sane with the first one just substract them and see the differance. You can also use a Gaussian filter to cut the high frequencies and subtract them and also put a threshhold to check if you want do the procesing or not